# Transforming an ODE into Legendre's Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, legendre-functions

> I am trying to transform the ODE $$\frac{1}{\sin(\theta)}\frac{d}{d\theta}\left(\sin(\theta)\frac{dS}{d\theta}\right)+\lambda S=0,$$ in to Legendre's equation $$(1-\mu^2)\frac{d^2S}{d\mu^2}-2\mu\frac{dS}{d\mu}+n(n+1)S=0$$ when $\lambda=n(n+1)$ for $n=0,1,2..$ and $\mu=\cos(\theta)$.

I calculated that,
\begin{align}
\frac{dS}{d\theta}&=\frac{dS}{d\mu}\frac{d\mu}{d\theta}=-\sin(\theta)\frac{dS}{d\mu} \\
\frac{d^2S}{d\theta^2}&=\frac{d}{d\theta}\left(\frac{dS}{d\theta}\right)=-\cos(\theta)\frac{d^2S}{d\mu^2}.
\end{align}
Then,
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\sin(\theta)}\left(\sin(\theta)\frac{d^2S}{d\theta^2}+\cos(\theta)\frac{dS}{d\theta}\right)+S\lambda&=0 \\
-\mu\frac{d^2S}{d\mu^2}-\mu\frac{dS}{d\mu}+n(n+1)S&=0.
\end{align}
But at this point, I don't see how Legendre's equation is possible. I know that the double derivative is calculated incorrectly, but I don't know how to rectify this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a mistake in deriving an expression for $\frac{d^2S}{d\theta^2}$. Let's have a look:
$$\frac{d^2S}{d\theta^2}=\frac{d}{d\theta}\left(\frac{dS}{d\theta}\right)=\frac{d}{d\theta}\left(-sin(\theta)\frac{dS}{d\mu}\right)=-\cos(\theta)\frac{dS}{d\mu} - sin(\theta)\frac{d}{d\theta}\left(\frac{dS}{d\mu}\right)=\\-\mu\frac{dS}{d\mu}- sin(\theta)\frac{d}{d\mu}\left(\frac{dS}{d\mu}\right)\cdot\frac{d\mu}{d\theta} =-\mu\frac{dS}{d\mu} + sin^2(\theta)\frac{d^2S}{d\mu^2}=\\-\mu\frac{dS}{d\mu} + (1-\mu^2)\frac{d^2S}{d\mu^2}$$
Plugging this into the original ODE you will get the Legendre differential equation.